# How to add multiple static variables as object?

Tags: javascript, function, object, constructor

I have a js function called StalkMe and I want to have a static variable for all the instances of that function.

The working code:

```
function StalkMe() {
    this.start = function() {
        while(true) {
            alert("Stalking "+StalkMe.period+" "+StalkMe.name+".");
        }
    }
}
StalkMe.period = "forever";
StalkMe.name = "John Doe";
```

What I want to write but doesn't work:

```
function StalkMe() {
    this.start = function() {
        while(true) {
            alert("Stalking "+StalkMe.period+" "+StalkMe.name+".");
        }
    }
}
StalkMe = {
    period: "forever",
    name: "John Doe"
}
```

Why doesn't the second method work?

And why can't I write `alert("Stalking "+this.period+" "+this.name+".");` ?

Comment: I've always had a bad time naming variables and functions the same name in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because with the second method you're overiding the base object. You first say StalkMe is a function and then say "oh no StalkMe is a literral object."

You are reasinigng it.

Comment: Is there some method to merge the object with the function without adding each variable one by one? Since ``StalkMe.prototype = "{*functions here*}"`` merges but that's because I used "prototype" :/

Comment: You can add your properties exactly the same way you are creating `start`

Comment: Otherwise take a look at your prefered search engine with keywords "merge Javascript objects"

Comment: but adding them as ``this.something`` inside the function like start makes them non static and added into the memory every time a new ``StalkMe`` object is created :/

Comment: I thought about using jQuery $.extend() but that's for 2 objects not for a method and an objects :/

Comment: @seahorsepip then just do `var period = forever;` on top of your object (before `start`) or make them global or finally, use a language that accepts static properties inside a class like TypeScript.

Comment: But seriously I don't think that the first method is a big issue.

Comment: Nah it's not really an issue, it's just something that always bugged me :P I'll look into typescript :)

Answer (score 0):

```
StalkMe = {
  period: "forever",
  name: "John Doe"
}
```

Here you are re-assigning StalkMe to an object which has only 2 keys named period,name nothing else. StalkMe is not object so that you can override it, its an constructor function, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you are reassigning the StalkMe object to an object literal.

Generally, you want to add the properties in the constructor and the methods to the prototype like this:

```
function StalkMe() {
  this.period = "forever";
  this.name = "John Doe";
}

StalkMe.prototype.start = function() {
  console.log("Stalking "+this.period+" "+this.name+".");
};

var stalker = new StalkMe();
stalker.start();
```

Note that it also works using `this` within the function to access the objects properties - as you requested.

Comment: Sadly adding period and name to the function itself makes them non static which results in them being copied to the memory on every StalkMe instance instead of just once...

Answer (score 0):

StackMe is a function n period n name are it's objects.
When u use StackMe.period = "forever" and StackMe.name = "John Doe" that means you're assigning a value to the object of the function.